# Mojo::DOM and Text Method to remove spaces

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo-useragent, mojo-dom

I have the following code which using Mojo::DOM to get the text

```
my $text =ua->get('https://my_site.org'.$_)->res->dom->at('div.container-fluid h1')->text;
```

while the text under h1 if on the following format :

```
<h1>
                       my_text                    </h1>
```

the $text is come with the heading and trailing spaces

I can do something like this to remove the heading and the trailing spaces

```
  $text =~ s/^\s+//;
  $text=~ s/\s+$//;
```

but I am wondering if its possible to do this with mojolicious functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mojo::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3A%3AUtil) provides [trim](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3A%3AUtil#trim) which should do what you want:

> `my $trimmed = trim $str;`
>
> Trim whitespace characters from both ends of string.